# how to create a function to pass beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a function that passes content to beautiful soup, but I either get indication error or it doesn't print out the text from the URL provided.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib.request
 def beautifulsoup(cont):
  url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning"
  content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup.get_text())
```

I expect to get a function which passes content to beautiful soup and prints out the text.

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read_content():  
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning"
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return soup.text


print(read_content())
```

Comment: thanks but want it defined as a function,can you help

Comment: thanks alot but want the content without the html tags,this worked before print(soup.get_text())

Comment: you can return soup.text, i have changed the answer